# Calling a user defined function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, function-calls, user-defined

I am trying to call a user defined function in jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnSun').click(function() {
    myFunction();
  });
  $.fn.myFunction = function() {
    alert('hi');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSun">Say hello!</button>
```

I tried the following as well:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnSun').click(function() {
    myFunction();
  });
});

function myFunction() {
  alert('hi');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSun">Say hello!</button>
```

It doesn't seem to work! Any idea where I am wrong?

Comment: I would define this as a **plugin**

Comment: just a remark, since you are using $.fn.myFunction, in most cases you are telling that you want to use this function over a valid wrapped jquery object, eg. `$('your_html_tag').myFunction()`. http://jsfiddle.net/H7z8f/

Answer (score 87, accepted):

If you want to call a normal function via a jQuery event, you can do it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnSun').click(myFunction);
});

function myFunction() {
  alert('hi');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSun">Say hello!</button>
```

Comment: If you need a custom function for an object (eg. a variable), you can use `Object.prototype.SayIt = function(s){return this+s;}; var ramone='Hey Ho, '; var s = 'Lets go'; console.log(ramone.SayIt(s));​`. If you have trouble, use `Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "SayIt", {value: function (s) { your stuff here }});`

Comment: @Nick Craver can you add parameters to user define function if so how would you use it {function myFunction(val1, val2) {
  //how would you use it here 
}} and how would you call the function... thanks

Comment: This didnt work for me. The one by Ruslan López Carro worked (its below.)

Comment: @NickCraver if `myFunction` take parameter how do you pass parameter to function `myFunction` during its call? Thanks

Answer (score 39):

Just try this. It always works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnSun').click(function() {
    $.fn.myFunction();
  });
  $.fn.myFunction = function() {
    alert('hi');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSun">Say hello!</button>
```

Comment: I was trying to waste my time in some stupid thing. I tried every code which is mention here but was unable to even `alert(0);` it. Was trying to figure out solution and here it was, I pressed `F12` and it seems my **AdBlocker** was blocking some contents from showing up. Read more:  [**Failed to load resource in chrome google.maps api**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34625042/5737774)

Answer (score 12):

They are called *plugins*, as Jaboc commented. To make sense, plugin function should do something with the element it is called through. Consider the following:

```
jQuery.fn.make_me_red = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        this.style.color = 'red';
    });
};

$('a').make_me_red();
```

Answer (score 10):

The following is the right method

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSun').click(function(){
        $(this).myFunction();
     });
     $.fn.myFunction = function() { 
        alert('hi'); 
     }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this `$('div').myFunction();`

This should work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#btnSun').click(function(){
  myFunction();
 });

function myFunction()
{
alert('hi');
}
```

Comment: So is it mean that we can't create user defined function in Jquery and call as we normally do?

Comment: Hey it works for me $('div').myFunction(); :-). Gr8 !!

Can you help me to understand this behavior ?? why we need $('div').myFunction()... why can't I call myFunction as normal function?

Comment: You are assinging it to the jQuery object.

Comment: because `myFunction` is not a normal function, it's a property of the jQuery object's prototype, which is why you can call `$('div').myFunction()`.  If you want to just be able to call `myFunction`, then why not just make a `function myFunction (){}`?

Answer (score 5):

```
jQuery.fn.make_me_red = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        this.style.color = 'red';
    });
};

$('a').make_me_red() // - instead of this you can use $(this).make_me_red() instead for better readability.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnSun').click(function(){

      myFunction();

   });

   $.fn.myFunction = function() { 
     alert('hi'); 

    }; 
});
```

Put ' ; ' after function definition...

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.fn.make_me_red = function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    $(this).siblings("#hello").toggle();
}
$("#user_button").click(function(){
    //$(this).siblings(".hello").make_me_red(); 
    $(this).make_me_red(); 
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
​
```

Function declaration and callback in [jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/nYdng/40/).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function hello(){
    console.log("hello")
}
$('#event-on-keyup').keyup(function(){
    hello()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="event-on-keyup">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.fn.clear = function()
{
    var $form = $(this);

    $form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, textarea').val('');
    $form.find('select option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
    $form.find('input:checkbox, input:radio').removeAttr('checked');

    return this;
}; 


$('#my-form').clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case I did

```
function myFunc() {
  console.log('myFunc', $(this));
}
$("selector").on("click", "selector", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  myFunc.call(this);
});
```

properly calls myFunc with the correct `this`.