# On click button is not calling function

Tags: jquery

For some reason the alert is not being called, can someone please help me debugg this?

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    // Keep filter hidden
    //$("#filter_bar").hide();

    $('#filter_bar').click(showFilterBar);

});

function showFilterBar(){
    alert('got in here');
    if ($("#filter_bar").is(":hidden")){
        $("#filter_bar").show();
    } 
    else
    {
        $("#filter_bar").hide();
    }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/imevax/1/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include JQuery :)

Working for me(Chrome):

http://jsbin.com/imevax/22/edit

All I did was include JQuery.

Edit: Updated to point to latest 1.x jquery version in a safe way as per @mattijo's suggestion.

Comment: My jquery is working on the page, but just not for the on click.

Comment: Your reference to jquery may not be working.  Are you using the CDN ("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js") ?

Comment: Oh nevermind, it was a mistake, I was calling the wrong button

Comment: @Austin - the JSBin you posted did not have JQuery included. You could see in the console - "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ". Once I included JQuery it started working for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
// Keep filter hidden
//$("#filter_bar").hide();

    $('#filter_bar').click(function(){
       alert('got in here');
       if ($("#filter_bar").is(":hidden")){
          $("#filter_bar").show();
       } 
       else
       {
          $("#filter_bar").hide();
       }
   });

});
```

You start jQuery events/functions etc like this:

```
$('#whatever').whatever(function(params){
  //code here
});
```

Comment: Can I not call a function?

Comment: cant you call the function like this? 

$('#filter_bar').click(function(){whatever();});

Comment: @cptnk he may not want to if he's calling the function in multiple places. In certain cases `name = function(){ ... }` can be advantageous.

Comment: @CodeMoose I just searched in stackoverflow and apearently he did it the right way.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520172/call-user-defined-function-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing the way you define your function:

```
showFilterBar = function(){
    alert('got in here');
    if ($("#filter_bar").is(":hidden")){
        $("#filter_bar").show();
    }else{
        $("#filter_bar").hide();
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () { 
    // Keep filter hidden
    //$("#filter_bar").hide();

    $('#filter_bar').click(showFilterBar);
});
```

Live: http://jsbin.com/imevax/15/edit