# Failed to load resource in chrome google.maps api

Tags: javascript

I have this error in chrome console:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

https://maps.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/22/2/intl/es_ALL/adsense.js
```

Anyone knows why I have this problem?

Comment: Also check this other posts about this matter: [I am getting Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT with Google chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318119/i-am-getting-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-blocked-by-client-with-google-chr) [Getting “net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT” error on some AJAX calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341765/getting-neterr-blocked-by-client-error-on-some-ajax-calls)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This type of errors are mostly due to an extension like Ad-block plus. Try disabling it for that website and that should fix that issue. You can also look at this question:
[I am getting Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT with Google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318119/i-am-getting-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-blocked-by-client-with-google-chr)

Comment: "Privacy Badger" had started blocking some corporate css and image files for me.

Answer (score 8):

Simply disabling extensions doesn't work; you can verify this by disabling your ad-blocking extension, reloading the page, and still seeing broken behavior.

The problem seems more closely related to cookies. You could delete all cookies from Google, but that is a pretty big hammer, with the downside of having to log back in to various Google properties.

Instead, you can remove the specific cookies that cause the issue:

1. Open maps.google.com
2. Click on the green "Secure" note to the left of the address bar.
3. Under "Cookies" it'll say "xx in use" -- click that text.
4. Expand "www.google.com" and "Cookies"
5. Remove all gsScrolPos cookies, by selecting one and clicking "Remove" (multi-select using the shift key doesn't seem to work)
6. Click reload (F5) -- maps will work.

Original link:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/AVmQTZfwtYw

Comment: This works for me. Thanks